# ymal error - ScannerError: while scanning a double-quoted scalar

Tags: python-3.x, yaml

I am getting the an error while accessing the yaml file

config.yaml

```
input_path: "/home/jupyter/Redacted_Contracts/test_path/*/*.pdf"
output_path: "/home/jupyter/gcs/"
```

when I run the following code

```
filename = 'config.yaml'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    with open(filename) as f:
        config = yaml.load(f, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
```

getting the below error message

```
ScannerError: while scanning a double-quoted scalar
  in "config.yaml", line 1, column 13
expected escape sequence of 8 hexadecimal numbers, but found 's'
  in "config.yaml", line 1, column 18
```

Comment: try single quotes?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in math mode -- storing parameter names like

```
--- 
params:
  - "$\alpha$"
  - "$\beta$" 
...
```

if you have something similar try either r string or single quotes as suggested above.

Edit: typos and cleanup

Answer (score 0):

Don't keep double quotes in yaml files

```yaml
input_path: /home/jupyter/Redacted_Contracts/test_path/*/*.pdf
output_path: /home/jupyter/gcs/
```

This will enable special character check in the value.